# Predicting intercept and coefficient for linear regression model for multiple variable

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have the following equation:

```
P = B0 + B1*Var1 + B2*Var2
```

I have the values of `P`, `Var1` and `Var2` with me. I tried to model this and then calculate the coefficients and intercept.

Below is the code and the output I am getting:

```
P = [1035.89, 1060.4, 1064, 1075.89, 1078.69, 1074.93, 1090.71, 1080.95, 1086.19,1080.46] # Total power

l = [51.275510204081634, 102.89115646258503, 160.7142857142857, 205.78231292517006, 256.80272108843536, 307.82312925170066, 360.5442176870748, 409.0136054421768, 460.03401360544217, 492.3469387755102]
t = [6.110918671507064, 12.262374116954474, 19.153625686813186, 24.524748233908948, 30.60526432496075, 36.685780416012555, 42.96898037676609, 48.7454706632653, 54.82598675431711, 58.67698027864992]


X = []
for index in range(0,len(P)):
    row = []
    row.append(t[index])
    row.append(l[index])
    X.append(row)

print "Using statsmodels"
import statsmodels.api as sm

X = sm.add_constant(X)
est = sm.OLS(P, X).fit()

print est.params[0]
print est.params[1]
print est.params[2]
```

I am getting the results as:

```
Using statsmodels
1048.32518503
0.0102496334198
0.0860026475829
```

Is this correct? Does `est.params[0]` refers to `B0` of the equation?
I get `B0` in the range of `600-650` when I run experiments?

Can this data mismatch because of wrong data ?

Comment: In addition to my answer below: Can you say anything about the background of the data? That might make it easier to find an appropriate model.

Comment: The data refers to values for energy consumption in smart phones.

Comment: Ok, I added another comment below my answer. A linear fit would describe the data well without the first data point but you would still be far away from B0 = 650. The observed mismatch is shortly mentioned in the answer, let me know if something else is needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with `statsmodels`, but here is an implementation using `curve_fit` (see the code below). The reason for the mismatch of the model prediction and the experimental result you observe is in my opinion that your model (`B0 + B1*Var1 + B2*Var2`) does not describe the data well (an exponential/log/sqrt would probably be better). In the next plots I show the original data, the fit obtained by `curve_fit` (code below) and the fit using your parameters.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the both fitting functions give the same result, however, your data should be modelled by another function, in my opinion. If I find time, I will look for function that fits your data better.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

P = [1035.89, 1060.4, 1064, 1075.89, 1078.69, 1074.93, 1090.71, 1080.95, 1086.19,1080.46] # Total power
l = [51.275510204081634, 102.89115646258503, 160.7142857142857, 205.78231292517006, 256.80272108843536, 307.82312925170066, 360.5442176870748, 409.0136054421768, 460.03401360544217, 492.3469387755102]
t = [6.110918671507064, 12.262374116954474, 19.153625686813186, 24.524748233908948, 30.60526432496075, 36.685780416012555, 42.96898037676609, 48.7454706632653, 54.82598675431711, 58.67698027864992]

# your model
def func(x, b0, b1, b2):

    var1, var2 = x

    return b0 + np.dot(b1, var1) + np.dot(b2, var2)

# Curve fit
coeff, _ = curve_fit(func, (l, t), P)
b0, b1, b2 = coeff[0], coeff[1], coeff[2]
print b0, b1, b2

# plot the data
xval = range(1 ,len(P)+1)
plt.scatter(xval, P, s=30, marker = "v", label='P')
plt.scatter(xval, func((l,t), *coeff), s=30, marker = "v", color="red", label='curvefit')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(xval, P, s=30, marker = "v", label='P')
plt.scatter(xval, func((l, t), 1048.32518503, 0.0860026475829, 0.0102496334198 ), s=30, marker = "v",color="black",label='your parameter')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
print "residuals curve_fit:",((P - func((l,t), *coeff))**2).sum()
print "residuals stats:",((P - func((l,t), 1048.32518503,0.086002647582,0.0102496334198))**2).sum()
```

Comment: The text explaining the model equation stresses that the equation is linear, hence a curve-fit would be somewhat diverting away from the model.(Please correct if this understanding is wrong).

Comment: Well, I do not know enough background of your data, unfortunately. I updated my post: In the original version, I confused your parameters (B1 and B2). Now your fitting method and curve_fit give identical results. The fit does not look awful; I was just thinking that another function would describe the data better but if the underlying model is "known" then it should be fine.  Does the answer answer your question or do you need something else? If so, let me know and I revise the code.